# Sorting union of streams to identify user sessions in Apache Flink

Tags: scala, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have two streams of events

- **L** = *(l1, l3, l8, ...)* - is sparser and represents user logins to a IP
- **E** = *(e2, e4, e5, e9, ...)* - is a stream of logs the particular IP

the lower index represents a timestamp... If we joined the two streams together *and sorted them by time* we would get:

- **l1**, *e2*, **l3**, *e4, e5*, **l8**, *e9*, ...

Would it be possible to implement custom `Window` / `Trigger` functions to group the event to sessions (time between logins of different users):

- **l1** - **l3** : *e2*
- **l3** - **l8** : *e4, e5*
- **l8** - **l14** : *e9*, *e10*, *e11*, *e12*, *e13*
- ...

The problem which I see is that the two streams are not necessarily sorted. I thought about sorting the input stream by time-stamps. Then it would be easy to implement the windowing using `GlobalWindow` and custom `Trigger` - yet it seems that it is not possible.

Am I missing something or is it definitely not possible to do so in current Flink (v1.3.2)?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Question: shouldn't E3 come before L4?

Sorting is pretty straightforward using a `ProcessFunction`. Something like this:

```
public static class SortFunction extends ProcessFunction<Event, Event> {
  private ValueState<PriorityQueue<Event>> queueState = null;

  @Override
  public void open(Configuration config) {
    ValueStateDescriptor<PriorityQueue<Event>> descriptor = new ValueStateDescriptor<>(
        // state name
        "sorted-events",
        // type information of state
        TypeInformation.of(new TypeHint<PriorityQueue<Event>>() {
        }));
    queueState = getRuntimeContext().getState(descriptor);
  }

  @Override
  public void processElement(Event event, Context context, Collector<Event> out) throws Exception {
    TimerService timerService = context.timerService();

    if (context.timestamp() > timerService.currentWatermark()) {
      PriorityQueue<Event> queue = queueState.value();
      if (queue == null) {
        queue = new PriorityQueue<>(10);
      }
      queue.add(event);
      queueState.update(queue);
      timerService.registerEventTimeTimer(event.timestamp);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onTimer(long timestamp, OnTimerContext context, Collector<Event> out) throws Exception {
    PriorityQueue<Event> queue = queueState.value();
    Long watermark = context.timerService().currentWatermark();
    Event head = queue.peek();
    while (head != null && head.timestamp <= watermark) {
      out.collect(head);
      queue.remove(head);
      head = queue.peek();
    }
  }
}
```

Update: see [How to sort an out-of-order event time stream using Flink](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59468154/2000823)
 for a description of a generally better approach.

Comment: Hello David, i think you will have a serialization / deser performance issue with this value state, if you get and update it at every message (w Rocksdb)

Comment: Yes, that's right. It's better to use MapState with RocksDB.

Comment: Yes thanks ! with timestamp as key, this could be a good idea ?

Comment: What I don't understand when `onTimer` fires it will release all events `<= watermark`. If I would have a window operation after the sort aren't there a lot of late arrivals since events get emitted smaller than the watermark?