# Flink: Append an event to the end of finite DataStream

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

Assuming there is a finite DataStream (from a database source, for example) with events

- `a1, a2, ..., an`.

How to append one more event `b` to this stream to get

- `a1, a2, ..., an, b`

(i.e. output the added event after all original events, preserving the original ordering)?

I know that all finite streams emit the `MAX_WATERMARK` after all events. So, is there a way to "catch" this watermark and output the additional event  after it?

(Unfortunately, `.union()`ing the original DataStream with another DataStream consisting of a single event (with timestamp set to `Long.MaxValue`) and then sorting the united stream using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54158843/how-to-sort-the-union-datastream-of-flink-without-watermark) did not work.)

Comment: Do you know the count ahead of time? Also, if it is a finite set, why can't you use the DataSet API instead of the DataStream?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something, but it seems like you could simply have a ProcessFunction with an event time timer set for somewhere in the distant future, so that it only fires when the MAX_WATERMARK arrives. And then in the onTimer method, emit that special event if the currentWatermark is MAX_WATERMARK.

Comment: Thanks! It worked for me. I didn't know that onTimer fires only when watermark arrives.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach might be to 'wrap' the original data source in another data source, which emits a final element when the delegate object's `run()` method returns. You'd need to be careful to call through to all of the delegate methods, of course.