# How to handle the case for watermarks when num of kafka partitions is larger than Flink parallelism

Tags: apache-flink

I am trying to figure out a solution to the problem of watermarks progress when the number of Kafka partitions is larger than the Flink parallelism employed.

Consider for example that I have Flink app with parallelism of 3 and that it needs to read data from 5 Kafka partitions. My issue is that when starting the Flink app, it has to consume historical data from these partitions. As I understand it each Flink task starts consuming events from a corresponding partition (probably buffers a significant amount of events) and progress event time (therefore watermarks) before the same task transitions to another partition that now will have stale data according to watermarks already issued.

I tried considering a watermark strategy using watermark alignment of a few seconds but that
does not solve the problem since historical data are consumed immediately from one partition and therefore event time/watermark has progressed.Below is a snippet of code that showcases watermark strategy implemented.

```
WatermarkStrategy.forGenerator(ws)
        .withTimestampAssigner(
            (event, timestamp) -> (long) event.get("event_time))
        .withIdleness(IDLENESS_PERIOD)
        .withWatermarkAlignment(
            GROUP,
            Duration.ofMillis(DEFAULT_MAX_WATERMARK_DRIFT_BETWEEN_PARTITIONS),
            Duration.ofMillis(DEFAULT_UPDATE_FOR_WATERMARK_DRIFT_BETWEEN_PARTITIONS));
```

I also tried using a downstream operator to sort events as described here [Sorting union of streams to identify user sessions in Apache Flink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47576408/sorting-union-of-streams-to-identify-user-sessions-in-apache-flink) but then again also this cannot effectively tackle my issue since event record times can deviate significantly.

How can I tackle this issue ? Do I need to have the same number of Flink tasks as the number of Kafka partitions or I am missing something regarding the way data are read from Kafka partitions

Comment: How are you using this watermark strategy? Are you passing it into `fromSource`, or applying it later using `assignTimestampsAndWatermarks`, or ... ?

Comment: I do apply it later indeed using assignTimestampsAndWatermarks, but immediately after reading from source.

Comment: Ok David I have missed that: https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.16/docs/dev/datastream/event-time/generating_watermarks/#watermark-alignment-_beta_. It is stated clearly there, on the relevant Note section, what my issue was

Comment: I have a similar issue in which I'm getting late events but only during savepoints/ checkpoint restore, not under normal execution. I am setting the watermark strategy on the source and allowing enough out of order lag to avoid this issue during normal execution. However, on restores, I am always get late events no matter how much I increase the out of order lag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution to this problem will be using the `fromSource` with `WatermarkStrategy` instead of assigning that by using `assignTimestampsAndWatermarks`.

When You use the `WatermarkStrategy` directly in `fromSource` with kafka connector, the watermarks will be partition aware, so the Watermark generated by the given operator will be minimum of all partitions assinged to this operator.

Assigning watermarks directly in source will solve the problem You are facing, but it has one main drawback, since the generated watermark in min of all partitions processed by the given operator, if some partition is idle watermark for this operator will not progress either.

The docs describe kafka connector watermarking [here](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.16/docs/dev/datastream/event-time/generating_watermarks/#watermark-strategies-and-the-kafka-connector).