# Too many messages outOfOrder with Flink Idleness configured

Tags: apache-flink

I'm using a periodic watermarking to order the messages by event time, however i'm getting big differences in the results if i configure "withIdleness".

Basically, i'm getting as outOfOrder ~90% of the messages if i use "withIdleness". Without i'm getting just ~5% outOfOrder.

**Environment:**

- Flink 1.15.2
- Parallelism 3
- AutoWatermarkInterval 200ms
- Source:

  - 3 kafka topics. 3 partitions each. All partitions/topics has messages

    - Topic one: 100k of messages
    - Topic two: 5k of messages
    - Topic three: 5k of messages
- Union the 3 kafkaSourceStream in one stream.
- Watermark Strategy in each kafka source:

```
WatermarkStrategy.<Event>forBoundedOutOfOrderness(Duration.ofSeconds(5))
        .withTimestampAssigner((element, recordTimestamp) -> element.getTimestamp())
        .withIdleness(Duration.ofSeconds(5));
```

- OutOfOrder sorting processor, i'm using [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47576408/sorting-union-of-streams-to-identify-user-sessions-in-apache-flink/47582271](https://stackoverflow.com) as example to test.

Q1: If we know that all the topics/partitions has messages, should we configure idleness? I have this question because after reprocess all this messages i will consume in a "regular way".

Q2: Let's assume that i have one more topic (a fourth topic) without messages. How should i process in this case? Should i configure idleness just for this topic?

Thanks for your help

---

I've changed my configuration for

```
WatermarkStrategy.<Event>forBoundedOutOfOrderness(Duration.ofSeconds(5))
        .withTimestampAssigner((element, recordTimestamp) -> element.getTimestamp())
        .withIdleness(Duration.ofSeconds(60));
```

and we got a big difference between flink 1.15.2 and 1.15.4.

Could be this [bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-28975) a reason for that?

- [Flink 1.15.4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFlIF.png)
- [Flink 1.15.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1WLHG.png)

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of withIdleness is to force operators waiting for a watermark to produce results without waiting any longer than the interval provided -- 5 seconds, in this case. It sounds like it's relatively common in your case for events to be 5 seconds (or more) apart, which is causing some headaches.

Q1: For topics where you expect every partition to have a continuous flow of events, don't use withIdleness.

Q2: Yes, in this case you should configure an idleness timeout. And set it to be large enough so it isn't going to be triggered during "business as usual".

---

There are two parameters involved in configuring a watermark strategy:

(1) The watermarking delay (the "bounded out of orderness") should be large enough to prevent an unreasonable number of events from being considered late, and small enough that the latency it causes is tolerable. In some cases you may find it desirable to put up with having some significant number of late events, in combination with capturing those late events and updating the previously emitted results to include those late events.

(2) In cases where a partition or topic may be empty, or become idle (e.g., overnight), you will need to configure an idle timeout to prevent the job from stalling. After timing out, Flink will ignore the lack of traffic for that partition or topic, and carry on as though that input source didn't exist. Once event traffic resumes, there is some risk that the initial events will be late.

The DataStream window and join operators ignore late events by default, as do SQL windows. The sorting example you're using also ignores (drops) late events.

Comment: Thanks David. I'm new in this concept of stream/Flink and i'm struggling a little bit.
Regarding Q2, is not clear for me when you say "...so it isn't going to be triggered during "business as usual", because we know that we are going produce results just after this value. If we set a large number here we are going to save a lot of events in the state without producing output. 
Thanks

Comment: I've expanded my answer.

Comment: Hey, i've added one last point to may question. Thanks a lot

Comment: I'd forgotten about that bug -- yes, that bug could have a very noticeable effect.